# How to maximize WRUs in DynamoDB?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I need to bulk insert records into a DynamoDB database on a weekly basis. I do this by dropping the table, creating a new table with On Demand capacity, then using BatchWriteItem to populate the table. According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadWriteCapacityMode.html), newly created tables with On Demand capacity can serve up to 4,000 WCUs. No matter what I try though the most I can get is 1,487 WCUs. I have tried the following:

- Randomizing the order of the records before writing to avoid hot partitions
- Splitting the records into groups and writing each group in parallel in its own Lambda function
- Running the process in different environments, including EC2, Lambda, and locally (locally is slower, presumably due to latency)
- Changing the capacity type from On Demand to Provisioned with 5 RCUs and 10,000 WCUs
- Utilizing async/await in different ways to try and maximize throughput (I am using the AWS SDK for .NET)

Although the throughput differs from experiment to experiment and from execution to execution, 1,487 WCUs comes up often enough that there may be some significance to it.

What do I need to do to leverage the full 4,000 WCUs available to me?

Comment: Are you actually getting `ProvisionedThroughputExceeded` exceptions or something like that? Otherwise the limit is the tool that writes to the table and not the service itself. Here the general approach would be to increase the number of threads/processes and parallelization in general.

Comment: Hi @Maurice, I am not getting a ProvisionedThroughputExceeded exception, however I sometimes get unprocessed items in the response. I use exponential backoff to reprocess these items. I have attempted to increase parallelization by fanning out the writing to multiple lambda functions. Do you think approach is appropriate?

Comment: In general that approach seems valid, but if it works depends a lot on the implementation. I'd expect that you can saturate the 1000 WRUs from a single machine with Multi-Threading using a sufficiently powerful server, network connection and C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your limitation appears to be on the writer side, I've written a small Python script to create and load test a table.

We can see that DynamoDB easily scales up to 4000 WRU with 8 worker processes, then throttles a bit and afterwards scales up again. To get more throughput, I'd have to add more writer processes:

[image: Write Request Units vs. Throttle Events]

Here is the script for your convenience:

```py
import multiprocessing
import typing
import uuid

import boto3
import boto3.dynamodb.conditions as conditions

from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

TABLE = "speed-measurement"
NUMBER_OF_WORKERS = 8

def create_table_if_not_exists(table_name: str):

    try:
        boto3.client("dynamodb").create_table(
            AttributeDefinitions=[{"AttributeName": "PK", "AttributeType": "S"}],
            TableName=table_name,
            KeySchema=[{"AttributeName": "PK", "KeyType": "HASH"}],
            BillingMode="PAY_PER_REQUEST"
        )
    except ClientError as err:
        if err.response["Error"]["Code"] == 'ResourceInUseException':
            # Table already exists
            pass
        else:
            raise err

def write_fast(worker_num):

    table = boto3.resource("dynamodb").Table(TABLE)

    counter = 0

    with table.batch_writer() as batch:
        while True:

            counter += 1
            
            result = batch.put_item(
                Item={
                    "PK": str(uuid.uuid4())
                }
            )

            if counter % 1000 == 0:
                print(f"Worker: #{worker_num} Wrote item #{counter}")

def main():
    create_table_if_not_exists(TABLE)
    
    with multiprocessing.Pool(NUMBER_OF_WORKERS) as pool:
        pool.map(write_fast, range(NUMBER_OF_WORKERS))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Just run it with Python 3 and stop it with Ctrl+C once you're seeing the desired metrics. It will create a table and just write as fast as it can in 8 processes. You can also increase this number.

Source for the CloudWatch Graphic:

```json
{
    "metrics": [
        [ { "expression": "m2/60", "label": "Write Request Units", "id": "e1", "color": "#2ca02c" } ],
        [ "AWS/DynamoDB", "WriteThrottleEvents", "TableName", "speed-measurement", { "yAxis": "right", "id": "m1" } ],
        [ ".", "ConsumedWriteCapacityUnits", ".", ".", { "stat": "Sum", "period": 1, "id": "m2", "visible": false } ]
    ],
    "view": "timeSeries",
    "stacked": false,
    "region": "eu-central-1",
    "stat": "Maximum",
    "period": 60,
    "yAxis": {
        "left": {
            "label": "Consumed Write Request Units",
            "showUnits": false
        },
        "right": {
            "label": "Write Throttle Events",
            "showUnits": false
        }
    },
    "annotations": {
        "horizontal": [
            {
                "color": "#9edae5",
                "label": "Initial Limit",
                "value": 4000,
                "fill": "below"
            }
        ]
    },
    "legend": {
        "position": "bottom"
    },
    "setPeriodToTimeRange": true
}
```

Comment: This is fantastic Maurice, thank you very much. Let me get this set up in my environment and I will report back.

Comment: :) - I've also added the source for the CloudWatch Metrics, so you can create the graph easily.

Comment: Oh no, I just realised what I was doing wrong; my data set wasn't big enough to fully leverage the available WCUs! Your graph is what tipped me off; I noticed that it was running for about 10-15 minutes whereas my tests were completing in about 30 seconds. I increased the size of my data set and was able to max out the WCUs. Thanks for your help Maurice :)